# Why are some equal values ​that are present in different relationship are truncated in Springboot response?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have a @ManyToMany relationship between these two entities:

```java
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Group {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private final List<Project> projects;

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Project {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "projects_groups",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")}
    )
    private final List<Group> groups;

}
```

When I get the responses the data are shown in this way:

## When I fetch the projects list

Same group id in different groups

```json
[
    {
        "id": "**0651465d52684039b9aed91f4098bb07**", // different project id
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "**977e779c44ed4ec78e14944ad800cc55**", // same group id
                "name": "**data**",
                "author": "**data**",
                "description": "**data**",
                "members": "**data**"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "**175b39d6392c405b86efee9d43057f6d**" // different project id
        "groups": [
            "**977e779c44ed4ec78e14944ad800cc55**" // same group id
        ]
    }
]
```

## When I fetch the groups list

Same project id in different groups

```json
[
    {
        "id": "5fe7ead781f7459d83d8c118c812f898", // different group id
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "**0651465d52684039b9aed91f4098bb07**", // same project id
                "name": ""**data**"",
                "author": ""**data**"",
                "shortDescription": ""**data**"",
                "description": ""**data**"",
                "version": ""**data**"",
                "updates": ""**data**"",
                "projectRepo": ""**data**""
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "977e779c44ed4ec78e14944ad800cc55", // different group id
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "**0651465d52684039b9aed91f4098bb07**", // same project id
                "name": ""**data**"",
                "author": ""**data**"",
                "shortDescription": ""**data**"",
                "description": ""**data**"",
                "version": ""**data**"",
                "updates": ""**data**"",
                "projectRepo": ""**data**""
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

So when I request the groups list the duplicate values of the projects are shown correctly, but when I request the projects list the duplicate values of the groups are shown as the first entry the total content of the group but the other entries only the id of the group.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was remove the

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
     generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
     property = "id"
)
```

from the Group class to show correctly the data